# Targets conflict when using CMake FetchContent

Tags: cmake, dependencies

On a CMake project, I am using FetchContent to get two dependencies. Both of them define the same target (in this case `doc`), resulting in an error at configuration step:

```
CMake Error at thirdparty/penf/doc/CMakeLists.txt:7 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "doc" because another target with
  the same name already exists.  The existing target is a custom target
  created in source directory
  "/home/me/project/thirdparty/flogging/doc".  See
  documentation for policy CMP0002 for more details.
```

How can I avoid this targets conflict?

Comment: Try to find an option in these projects (at least, in one of them) to disable documentation building. If none of the project has such possibility, then you should replace `FetchContent` approach with something else. E.g. with `ExternalProject_Add`.