# CMake Dependency Management

Tags: c++, c, git, cmake, dependency-management

I am looking for some insights in proper CMake dependency management. I've come across `ExternalProject` and `FetchContent` and both don't completely fulfill my needs. Let me explain in detail:

My project has the following structure:

```
main_project/
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── external/
│   ├── submodule1/
│   ├── submodule2/
│   ├── submodule3/
│   .
│   .
│   .
```

Each `submoduleN` is a git submodule which contains a full grown up CMake project with its own **install targets**. I have full control over those submodules (I write them). I want to use **install targets** because they provide the external interface to the submodules (with proper namespacing etc.). I [**do not want to use the internal build targets**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66166690/8088550). I want to use `find_package` to resolve dependencies.

Secondly, I do not want to use some download mechanism to get and deploy depedencies. I want to use git submodules for this, because

- I can freeze submodule version in the main project (dependency version management).
- I can checkout any other version easily for debugging (no editing of files, just use git and have the full commit messages for reference at hand).

Assume that each `submoduleN` has its own, similar substructure and they possibly depend on each other internally. I want them to use a single, common version if they happen to have a shared dependency. Hierarchy in the main project takes precedence for the version selection. For instance, something similar as `FetchContent`'s populate idiom:

```
FetchContent_GetProperties(mylib)
if(NOT mylib_POPULATED)
  FetchContent_Populate(mylib)
  # do build, install and other stuff
endif()
```

I want install targets to be usable at the configure step (i.e. `find_package`) and I want them to be rebuilt if I edit them (i.e. apply some debugging changes in one `submoduleN`).

Problem:

- I cannot use `ExternalProject_Add` because it's only available at build stage.
- I cannot use `FetchContent` because it ignores install targets (doesn't even build them).
- I cannot use `FetchContent` because there will be duplicate target names (doc, main, tests, etc.).

I know of [Hunter++](https://hunter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which almost solves my problem, except for the gitsubmodule and no-download part. I made a partly working example with `ExternalProject`, but I find it very messy and it doesn't solve the common version problem:
https://github.com/image357/cmake_tutorial_external

Any ideas?

---

EDIT:

I just found out about a proposal at CMake for something similar:
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21687

Comment: FWIW, what I do in these circumstances is build the dependencies with a `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to a local directory and add that directory to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` when building the root project. It does mean that building is a two-stage process, but it's ultimately much cleaner.

Comment: This is a fantastic question that points out some serious issues with the dependency management story in CMake. I have some thoughts on this that I'll try to pull together into an answer.

Comment: You definitively need to read the original issue #17735 (in ref of the issue 21687)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick update: It seems that [Hunter](https://hunter.readthedocs.io) has a git submodule mode: https://hunter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guides/hunter-user/git-submodule.html

Thus it actually fits my use case perfectly.

Have this is in your `CMakeLists.txt`

```
include(your/local/path/to/HunterGate.cmake)
HunterGate(
        URL "https://github.com/cpp-pm/hunter/archive/v0.23.320.tar.gz"
        SHA1 "9b4e732afd22f40482c11ad6342f7d336634226f"
        LOCAL
)

hunter_add_package(mysubmodule_lib)
find_package(mysubmodule_lib CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

Have this at `cmake/Hunter/config.cmake` in your project:

```
hunter_config(mysubmodule_lib GIT_SUBMODULE your/path/to/mysubmodule_lib VERSION 1.2.3)
```